# C++ vector<vector<double>> using typename alias

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm new to c++ and trying to set up a matrix properly.  My data will have an unknown number of rows but will have 6 columns and I was thinking of using either vector> or boost multiarray package.  Can I set something up like:

```
template<size_t t>

using Matrix <t> = vector<vector<double>> m(t, vector<double>(6))
```

or would this not work/ is not appropriate/not advised?

Comment: Make a vector of 6 arrays

Comment: Why don't you simply try if it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc9a9e3295e3dd5b)?

Comment: I think you compiler may not like this syntax very much. Template is quite compile time thing so very likely don't allow you do anything dynamic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template< typename T, size_t n >
using Matrix = std::vector< std::array< T, n > >;

typedef Matrix< double, 6 > SpecificMatrix;

int main()
{
  SpecificMatrix my_matrix(10);
  double x = 0;

  for (auto &a : my_matrix)
    for (auto &b : a)
      b = (x += 1.0);

  std::cout << "My thingy:" << std::endl;

  for (auto &a : my_matrix)
  {
    for (auto &b : a)
      std::cout << b << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```